# Django ORM problems with AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, postgresql

I have question aobut Django ORM with ajax request on function:

> select_related

I have query like this:

```
prod_serv = Product_service.objects.select_related()
```

Where I join 3 `models` on foreign key with `related_name`.
In simple Django for loop i can extract values like this:

```
{% for x in a %}
                        <td><label class="form-checkbox form-normal form-primary "><input type="checkbox" checked=""></label></td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.product_code }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.name }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.description }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.selling_price }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.unit_id }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ x.category_id.type_id }}</td>

                    {% endfor %}
```

The most importan part is :

1. x.category_id.type_id
2. x.unit_id

Where I can access values related name. 
Example:

## models

```
class Product_service(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="/", blank=True, null=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_code_supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_code_buyer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    min_unit_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vat_id = models.ForeignKey('VatRate', related_name='vat_rate')
    unit_id = models.ForeignKey('Units', related_name='unit_value')
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='product_services')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Units(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit_name

class VatRate(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rate


class CategoryType(models.Model):
    id   = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_id = models.ForeignKey('CategoryType')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

The siple for loop doing everthin right, but I wanna do this with ajax. So when i send this query to ajax i cant extract values like in for loop.

## views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def ajax_request(request):


    prod_serv = Product_service.objects.select_related()

    if request.is_ajax():
        mega = serializers.serialize('json', prod_serv)
        return HttpResponse(mega, 'json')
```

I dont know what Im I doing wrong in this query sending it to ajax. Is there some other way to send values to ajax with extracted fields from models?

Comment: Maybe it'd be more convenient for you to JSON-ify that prod_serv Queryset as a List of Lists, and convert to JSON only the values you need? Something like `prod_serv = Product_service.objects.values_list('category_id__type_id', 'unit_id')`, then `mega = serializers.serialize('json', list(prod_serv))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are using Django and Ajax, you should be thinking of a rest framework (like [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)).  Hand-rolling your own ajax & endpoints is reinventing the wheel, while other very smart people have open sourced their code for you.  Using a framework with Ajax lets you break your model manipulation out of the Django request-response cycle and handle things really easily in the browser.

There are 3 steps:

1. Install DRF and set up some model endpoints
2. Write the ajax request to hit your endpoint
3. Manipulate the DOM based on the response.

Example template:

## template.html

```
{% block extra_js %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Forgive the pseudocode, I have not run this.
    // Uses jquery because everything does.

    // For each item in an array, add it to a selected table in a new row
    var do_dom_manipulation = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(d){
            $('table.mytable').append('<tr>'+d+'<tr>')
        })
    }

    // Hit the rest endpoint to get data from the browser
    $.ajax('api/models',
        {
            'name': 'foo'
        }
    ).done(function(data) {
        alert( "success" );
        do_dom_manipulation(data)
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
    });
</script> 

{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Comment: Yea when I go with Rest Framework query works fine. Thx for solution. @bwarren2

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
import django.utils.simplejson as json

json.dumps(prod_serv)
```

OR you can use serializer

```
from django.core import serializers
# serialize queryset
serialized_queryset = serializers.serialize('json', prod_serv)
```